# How to 301 redirect via htacces

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to setup a 301 redirect for the following link:

```
https://www.domain.de/aaa/bbb/
```

and i wanna redirect it to:

```
https://www.domain.de/ccc.html
```

and thats what i already tried:

```
Redirect 301 /aaa/bbb/ https://www.domain.de/ccc.html

RewriteRule ^aaa/bbb/$ /ccc.html? [L,R=301]
```

and

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /aaa/bbb/ /ccc.html

</IfModule>
```

none of them worked for me. Any hints for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
RedirectMatch /aaa/bbb/(.+)$ https://example.com/$1.html
```

Short explanation : 
The regex capture-group `(.+)` captures everything after `/aaa/bbb/` and saves the captured value in `$1` variable and then we  use the `$1` in the destination url.

This is doing a temporary (302 default status) redirection from `/aaa/bbb/foobar/` to `/foobar.html` . If you want a permanent (301) url redirecton, simply add a 301 status  code to the directive ie: `RedirectMatch 301 pattern destination` .